# How long will it take google to index my site after robots.txt change?

Tags: wordpress, seo, robots.txt

I am working on this site: www.pjarchitects.com. It is a Wordpress build. When the site initially went live I had the " Discourage search engines from indexing this site" box checked. It is now unchecked and I want my site to be crawled and indexed by google but I still get this message when searching google "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

My site passed the robots.txt tester in Webmaster Tools. IS there a certain amount of time I need to wait ( It has been a day already) Or is there something else causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly about 24 hours until they recrawl the robots.txt, but it could take longer before the text in the actual SERP (Search engine results pages) is updated with the appropriate meta description.